# script to mask a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a code where if i pass a inputdata as "sail" my code will generate a masked output such as "aisl" or "isal". where the output will be jumbled format of input. I want to have a output which should not generate the output with the same exact letters in the input.Below is my current code and please help me with this

```
        string InputData = "123456";
        string MaskedData = InputData;

        if (MaskedData.Length > 0)
        {
            // The technique used to mask the data is to replace numbers with random numbers and letters with letters
            //char[] chars = new char[InputData.Length];
            char[] chars = new char[InputData.Length];

            Random rand = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            int index = 0;

            while (InputData.Length > 0)
            {
                // Get a random number between 0 and the length of the word.
                int next = rand.Next(0, InputData.Length - 1);

                // Take the character from the random position and add to our char array.
                //chars[index] = InputData[next];
                chars[index] = InputData[next];

                // Remove the character from the word.
                InputData = InputData.Substring(0, next) + InputData.Substring(next + 1);

                ++index;
            }

            MaskedData = new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: why not just get a random letter from the alphabet?

Comment: Shuffle the character array and generate a string.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, why not use a hash algorithm? Seems to me like you're trying to reinvent that wheel.

Comment: This should be enough: `Random r = new Random(); string shuffled = new string(InputData.OrderBy(x=> r.Next()).ToArray());`

Answer (score 1):

[In this page in dotnetperls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle) there is an algorithm that randomizes an array of strings. With a few changes you can use it to randomize a string, using the fact that a string is also an array of chars. Here you have:

```
static class RandomCharArrayTool
{
    static Random _random = new Random();

    public static string RandomizeChars(string theString)
    {
        var arr = theString.ToCharArray();
        List<KeyValuePair<int, char>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, char>>();
        // Add all strings from array
        // Add new random int each time
        foreach (char s in arr)
        {
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, char>(_random.Next(), s));
        }
        // Sort the list by the random number
        var sorted = from item in list
             orderby item.Key
             select item;
        // Allocate new string array
        char[] result = new char[arr.Length];
        // Copy values to array
        int index = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, char> pair in sorted)
        {
            result[index] = pair.Value;
            index++;
        }
        // Return string generated from copied array
        return new string(result);
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
RandomCharArrayTool.RandomizeChars("sail");
```

Comment: I like the cover all basis approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**Mehtod 1:**

```
string word = "123456";
string temp = word;
string result = string.Empty;
Random rand = new Random();

for (int a = 0; a < word.Length; a++)
{
    //multiplied by a number to get a better result, it was less likely for the last index to be picked
    int temp1 = rand.Next(0, (temp.Length - 1) * 3);

    result += temp[temp1 % temp.Length];
    temp = temp.Remove(temp1 % temp.Length, 1);

}

string str = result;
```

**Method2:**

```
var rnd = new Random();
string InputData = "123456";
string MaskedData = new string(InputData.OrderBy(r => rnd.Next()).ToArray());
```

Comment: I like method two, clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have several different approaches, however the easiest may be to implement a `SecureString` or a `Hash`.  One of those two would encrypt your data quite easily.  Under the notion the `mask` is to hide said contents.

```
// SecureString
var secure = new SecureString();
foreach(var character in textbox.Text.ToCharArray())
     secure.AppendChar(character);
```

Once your `string` is placed on memory, it would be encrypted on memory.  That is a rough implementation, but documentation will help you refine the approach to your needs.

```
// Hash (BCrypt for simplicity)
private const int factor = 12;
var hashed = BCrypter.HashPassword(textbox.Text, BCrypter.GenerateSalt(factor));
```

Another approach would simply be randomization, similar to a word shuffle.  Like the other answers have demonstrated.